# как вывести результат LINQ запроса с анонимным типом в представление

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

у меня имеется простенькая база данных, созданная средствами EF Code First. Таблицы:
Products (ProductId,Name,Cost,Description,Date);
Customers (CustomerId,Name,Surname,Date,Email);
Orders (OrderId,CustomerId,ProductId,Count,Date).

Вот структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я создал контроллер MVC5 с представлениями, использующий Entity Framework. Запустил приложение и наполнил созданную базу данными. У меня было следующее задание, сделать форму для ввода даты начала и даты конца, после чего должна выводиться статистика по продажам за эти даты (сколько всего продаж и на какую сумму). Я добавил метод Report() в ранее созданном контроллере OrdersController, работающий на Get и Post запросы:

```
 public ActionResult Report()
    {

        return View();
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Report(ReportModel incomingData)
    {
        //Вычисление количества продаж
        int count;
        if (incomingData.StartDate != null && incomingData.EndDate != null)
        {
            count = (from x in db.Orders where (x.Date >= incomingData.StartDate && x.Date <= incomingData.EndDate) select x).Count();
        }
        else count = 0;
        ViewBag.Count = count;
        //вычисление суммы по этим продажам
        decimal? result;
        if (incomingData.StartDate != null && incomingData.EndDate != null)
        {
            result=(from o in db.Orders
                      join p in db.Products on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                      let amount = o.Count * p.Cost
                      where (o.Date >= incomingData.StartDate && o.Date <= incomingData.EndDate)
                      select amount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
        }
        else result = 0;
        ViewBag.Result = result;       
        return View();
    }
```

Вот моё представление Report.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
 }

<h2>Report</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>Start Date</label>
        @Html.TextBox("StartDate")
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>End Date</label>
        @Html.TextBox("EndDate")
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Check" />

</fieldset>
}
<div>Всего продаж @ViewBag.Count</div>
<div>Общая стоимость @ViewBag.Result</div>
```

Вроде, у меня всё получилось сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее стоит задание сделать форму для отслеживания покупок по отдельным пользователям. Правильные ли дальше мои действия? Я добавляю форму на ввод фильтра(например, имени) в представление:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div>
    <label>Введите имя пользователя </label>
    @Html.TextBox("y")
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Запросить статистику" />
```

}

Далее я преобразую метод [HttpPost] Report(), добавляя параметр string y (имя Customer'a):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Report(ReportModel incomingData,string y)
    {
        //Вычисление количества продаж
        int count;
        if (incomingData.StartDate != null && incomingData.EndDate != null)
        {
            count = (from x in db.Orders where (x.Date >= incomingData.StartDate && x.Date <= incomingData.EndDate) select x).Count();
        }
        else count = 0;
        ViewBag.Count = count;
        //вычисление суммы по этим продажам
        decimal? result;
        if (incomingData.StartDate != null && incomingData.EndDate != null)
        {
            result=(from o in db.Orders
                      join p in db.Products on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                      let amount = o.Count * p.Cost
                      where (o.Date >= incomingData.StartDate && o.Date <= incomingData.EndDate)
                      select amount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
        }
        else result = 0;
        ViewBag.Result = result;   
        //Вывод статистики по конкретному пользователю
         var query = from c in db.Customers
                    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                    join p in db.Products on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                    where c.Name==y
                    select new
                    {
                        c.CustomerId,
                        c.Name,
                        c.Surname,
                        Product=p.Name,
                        p.Cost,
                        c=o.Count,
                        d=o.Date
                    };
        ViewBag.Query = query;
        return View();
    }
```

После этого пытаюсь перебрать ViewBag.Query в представлении:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Report";
}
<h2>Report</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>Start Date</label>
        @Html.TextBox("StartDate")
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>End Date</label>
        @Html.TextBox("EndDate")
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Check" />

</fieldset>
}
<div>Всего продаж @ViewBag.Count</div>
<div>Общая стоимость @ViewBag.Result</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <label>Введите имя пользователя </label>
    @Html.TextBox("y")
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Запросить статистику" />
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("CustomerId")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Surname")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Product")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Cost")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Count")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Date")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Query)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

После этого моё приложение падает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чем может быть моя ошибка. Я думал, что может быть не городить всё в одном представлении, а сделать отдельное строготипизированное, которое отображала бы результат моего запроса LINQ, но Т.к. при выводе моего запроса используется анонимный тип, то представление нужно типизировать моделью:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVC_Fund6_2.Models
  {
public class X
    {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Я создал эту модель но типизировать ею представление тоже не получается. В итоге получилось только создать отдельный контроллер, в нем создал метод Statistic():

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using MVC_Fund6_2.Models;

 namespace MVC_Fund6_2.Controllers
{
public class testController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
    // GET: test
    public ActionResult Statistic()
    {
        var query = from c in db.Customers
                    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                    join p in db.Products on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId //
                    select new
                    {
                        c.CustomerId,
                        c.Name,
                        c.Surname,
                        Product = p.Name,
                        p.Cost,
                        o.Count,
                        o.Date
                    };
        return View(query.ToList());
    }
}
}
```

Представление: Statistic.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Statistic";
}

<h2>Statistic</h2>

<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

Получил следующий вид, но это совсем не то, что мне нужно. Не знаю как это отобразить в табличном виде. Такое ощущение, что это костыль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста мою ошибку, и если я делаю неправильно, направьте в нужном направлении. Спасибо!

Comment: Конечно, гораздо лучше использовать типизированную модель вместо анонимного класса. | Вы вставляете @item целиком в td. А нужно каждое свойство поместить в свою ячейку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если пишу <td>@item.CustomerId </td> то получается ошибка

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, зачем так далеко ходить до хрустального шара. Ошибка такая же как и в скриншоте. Можете пример привести как использовать типизированную модель?

Answer (score 1):

Материализуйте результаты запроса через `ToList();`

Comment: а в каком именно месте материализовать? у меня же там стоит return View(query.ToList())

Comment: Ну в этой части "Далее я преобразую метод [HttpPost] Report(), добавляя параметр string y (имя Customer'a):" не стоит.

Comment: Не помогает. (http://qar.site/questions/168928/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x) вот здесь решение есть, не могли бы Вы мне помочь его воплотить. (в ссылку нужно написать quaru.site - добавить "u", иначе ссылку не дает сделать) не понимаю как в LINQ в Select вывести экземпляр модели в моем случае

Answer (score 0):

В общем не получилось у меня никак засунуть во ViewBag коллекцию, а потом перебрать её через foreach в представлении.(я так понял, что шарп ждёт от меня во ViewBag тип ojbect). Поэтому после многих советов решил всё отделить разными представлениями, предварительно типизировав их моделями. Итак, для статистики по фамилии или имени или CustomerId я сделал модель:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVC_Fund6_2.Models
{
public class X
  {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Создал два метода контроллера, один на ГЕТ, второй на ПОСТ:

```
 public ActionResult Statistic()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Statistic(string y)
    {
        var query = (from c in db.Customers.AsEnumerable()
                     join o in db.Orders.AsEnumerable() on c.CustomerId equals 
                     o.CustomerId
                     join p in db.Products.AsEnumerable() on o.ProductId equals 
                     p.ProductId 
                     where c.Name == y || c.Surname == y || 
                     (c.CustomerId).ToString()==y
                     select new X
                     {
                         CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                         Name = c.Name,
                         Surname = c.Surname,
                         Product = p.Name,
                         Cost = p.Cost,
                         Count = o.Count,
                         Date = o.Date
                     }).ToList();
        return View("Succes", query);

    }
```

А также несколько View() , первое, которое работает на ввод данных:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Statistic";
}

<h2>Statistic</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <label>Введите имя пользователя,или фамилию или Id </label>
    @Html.TextBox("y")
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Запросить статистику" />
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Statistic")
</div>
```

Второе (создал Скаффолдингом ), на вывод статистики:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_Fund6_2.Models.X>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Succes";
}

<h2>Succes</h2>


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cost)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Такой вариант меня вполне устраивает. Дельного больше ничего не посоветовали. Но осталось так и непонятным, как результат нескольких коллекций внести в одну View()